# Display parent categories on left side bar

Tags: category, sidebar

Suppose below is my hierarchy :

```
Default Category
    Women  (30)
    Men  (50)
    Accessories (25)
```

Now I want to display women,men and Accessories category in left navigation menu.These categories has not any child categories,just have products.

Comment: are you want to show this filter depends on current apply filter

Comment: Sorry but am not getting you.

Comment: **manage store -> click the link->storename(select parant category) **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:-

app/design/frontend/default/your-bespoke-design-template/template/catalog/navigation/leftnav.phtml

```
<?php
    $currentCat = Mage::registry('current_category');

    if ( $currentCat->getParentId() == Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId() )
    {
        // current category is a toplevel category
        $loadCategory = $currentCat;
    }
    else
    {
        // current category is a sub-(or subsub-, etc...)category of a toplevel category
        // load the parent category of the current category
        $loadCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCat->getParentId());
    }
    $subCategories = explode(',', $loadCategory->getChildren());

    foreach ( $subCategories as $subCategoryId )
    {
        $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCategoryId);

        if($cat->getIsActive())
        {
            echo '<a href="'.$cat->getURL().'">'.$cat->getName().'</a>';
        }
    }
?>
```