# Magento 2 - Category Listing in Left sidebar

Tags: magento2

How to show list of categories and child categories in the left side bar of the category page and some cms pages

Comment: Can refer to http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101147/magento-2-show-category-tree-in-left-navigation
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72469/display-parent-categories-on-left-side-bar

Comment: I used ,but it displayed only main category

Comment: Please refer this post https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122363/magento-2-category-listing-in-left-column